# how to get swipe in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to swipe images in windows phone 7.
Where do I begin from?

Comment: What does "swipe"ing an image mean?

Comment: By swipe  I meant a gesture where touch and drag and leave will kind of flip the page

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `GestureService` in the [Silverlight Control Toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034). In your UI element, add the following piece of code (after you have referenced the toolkit's DLL in your WP7 project) -

```
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

Implement the handler OnFlick in the code-behind file, like so -

```
private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
{
   var vm = DataContext as SelectedCatalogViewModel;
   if (vm != null)
   {
      // User flicked towards left
      if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
      {
         // Load the next image 
         LoadNextPage(null);
      }

      // User flicked towards right
      if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
      {
         // Load the previous image
         LoadPreviousPage();
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps,
indyfromoz

Comment: What does "var vm = DataContext as SelectedCatalogViewModel;" mean?

Comment: The page that requires a swipe gesture implemented is bound to a ViewModel. The ViewModel class is SelectedCatalogViewModel and I am using MVVMLight's (MVVM toolkit) RelayCommand to wire up events from the code-behind with the underlying ViewModel. Sorry about the confusion. Cheers, indyfromoz

Comment: You might also want to make sure that the horizontal velocity is greater (by an order of magnitude, even) than the vertical velocity as well, so that diagonal or mostly vertical swipes don't trigger the `LoadNextPage` and `LoadPreviousPage` methods.

Comment: @pho79: or check (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)

Comment: here's the part you need in your xaml:

    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

Comment: it doesnt fired when "User flicked towards left" on LandScape Mode.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use the silverlight toolkit you can use the XNA framework.

http://www.nickharris.net/2010/11/using-touchpanel-for-gestures-in-windows-phone-7/

Comment: But as far as the documents say..XNA framework is for Gaming..Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the XNA framework works on WP7 for WP7 gaming, so you can reference the gestures part of the framework for a normal application just fine. Means you don't have to rely on 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

public partial class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(asd);
        gl.Flick += new EventHandler<FlickGestureEventArgs>(GestureListener_Flick);
    }

    private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Direction == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0) // determine direction (Right > 0)
            {
                //Some Action
            }
            else
            {
                //Some Action
            }
        }
    }
}
```