# Manipulation events in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing Windows phone 7 application, I need to do a slide show like application. I have the File[] when I swiping left or right the previous or next Image should show.  how to Do it?  I think it is possible through Manipulation events. but how to do this , I dont know Can u explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to create this effect woudl be something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="A.png" />
        <Image Source="B.png" />
        <Image Source="C.png" />
        <Image Source="D.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Although you could add the images through code.

If you want something more complex in your animation or need control over how an image can be interacted with you may want to do something different.

Before trying to use manipulations you may be able to use the `Flick` event from the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) which may make what you're trying to achieve easier.

It will all depend on what you're trying to do. Your question isn't explicitly clear.

See also [how to get swipe in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/how-to-get-swipe-in-windows-phone-7)