# Pivot with many PivotItems

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I'm developing a TV listing app for WP7, but I'm experiencing issues with the Pivot control: I tried at first to add all the available EPG channels, but performance are extremely poor (even on the real phone), taking ~10-15sec to add 25 **empty** PivotItems, without any data or control.

So I tested a dynamic/lazy load oriented approach that loads only three items at first and then adds one more each time the user swipes left or right. Problem is, when swiping left the new item pushes the current one in the databound collection one slot to the right, producing a messy rendering on screen: **that's not surprising, since SelectedIndex doesn't change, but selected item does**. However, fixing SelectedIndex makes things even worse, resulting in Pivot to get stuck in an inconsistent layout.

Here's the code:

```
    public void ChangeChannel(){

        if (index < 0) return;
        int i = index;
        int tot = Epg.Channels.Count;
        int slack = (i == 0) ? -1 : i > oldIndex ? 1 : -1;

        var ch = this.Channels[i];
        var nextIndex = (ch.ChannelIndex + slack) % tot;
        if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex += tot;

        var next = Epg.Channels[nextIndex];
        if (!this.Channels.Contains(next))
        {
            if (slack < 0)
            {
                this.Channels.Insert(0, next);
                //Index++;
            }
            else
                this.Channels.Add(next);
        }

        oldIndex = i;
    }
```

Method is associated to Pivot.LoadingPivotItem by means of Caliburn.Micro. *index* is bound to Pivot.SelectedIndex, *Epg.Channels* is the primary model object and *this.Channels* is an ObservableCollection bound to Pivot.ItemsSource

**EDIT: Found the trick.** I got suspicious when I recalled I have a RSS Reader app that has a Pivot with no less than 10-12 tabs working really fast. That said, I built a little test app working similarly but without using Caliburn. Oh, that's some performance! But is Caliburn so heavy? Not really, since I discovered this little piece of code in the default AppBootstrapper:

```
            ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<Pivot>(Pivot.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged").ApplyBinding =
            (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
            {
                if (ConventionManager
                    .GetElementConvention(typeof(ItemsControl))
                    .ApplyBinding(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention))
                {
                    ConventionManager
                        .ConfigureSelectedItem(element, Pivot.SelectedItemProperty, viewModelType, path);
                    ConventionManager
                        .ApplyHeaderTemplate(element, Pivot.HeaderTemplateProperty, viewModelType);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };
```

Removing it boosts performance, without having to quit Caliburn. Yeah, I know, that is something to investigate further, but for now it fixed all the stuff.

Comment: Don't do this. Do you really expect a user to flick through 25 items using a Pivot? I remember reading a guideline somewhere that said you should not have more than about 7-8 items in a Pivot, and that's a very good rule IMO. You should categorize the channels and create a main page containing a ListBox, or maybe even a Pivot with each category occupying a PivotItem. When the user makes a selection to view a category navigate to another Pivot that displays all the channels in that category.

Comment: @Praetorian Of course not, and in fact there's a quick channel selection page in the app.

Answer (score 3):

Anything above 5 items in a pivot is likely to have a noticabel performance impact.
Having the user trying to navigate between a large number of items is also likley to be very hard.

If you really need to use a pivot to show a large numebr of items you can do this by creating an instance with just 3 items in it and updating the bindings of each item as the selected item changes.
The aim is to populate the items either side of the one that is currently displayed. The logic can get a bit messy (dependent upon the currently selected item and the previously displayed item, update the other binding) but it is do-able.

Comment: Tried out, but performance is worst I've seen so far, even varying strategies (item replacement vs. binding update). I don't know, maybe I'll keep a right-swipe only lazy loading, which work pretty well and smoothly, but still it a real shame...

Comment: @MattLacey I'm binding pivot to my ViewModel (which has 3 item, so that pivot will generate 3 PivotItem). The problem is that when I update my ViewModel, the current pivot item and the pivot item to the right is updated. But the pivot item to the left (which is not on the screen) is not updated. You can encounter this when drag to the left. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [custom handling of flicking left/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/how-to-get-swipe-in-windows-phone-7) instead, and then just update the content as you go. With animations you can simulate transitions.

I've once created a comic reader this way. It's very easy, and doesn't impact performance.

Comment: how can I simulate animation like pivot ?