# Image Slide Show in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, slideshow

I am New to Windows Phone Dev. I like to Do one App after Using this App in Windows Phone
 [EspnCrickinfo](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/espncricinfo/1e64e7de-a62c-4baf-8a66-4433bd9b648a) App. When I use this App,i seen Very cool feather that Image in gallery Swiping Left and Right. I am trying this Functionally But I am Not Succeed.

I have Some JSON Link Contains Images

For Reference
I follow this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232764.aspx) But I am Getting Btns on App bar.

Please can any one suggest Me how can make this Easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hear is the Perfect Answer for This Question...[Image Slide Show with Swipe Effect in Windows Phone](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Picasa_Image_Gallery_with_JSON_in_WP7)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to have swipe effects go for microsoft toolkit and use gesture listener.
register to a flick event and you have your desired effect. This link will help you.

[how to get swipe in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/how-to-get-swipe-in-windows-phone-7)