# Detect flick on element, from left to right, and right to left

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can i detect a flick over a textblock on a windows phone 8 project, that when it comes from left to right does one thing and from right to left does another?
i tried using MouseLeave="Titulo_MouseLeave" on my element, but it dind't quite work

Comment: You have your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/how-to-get-swipe-in-windows-phone-7 [duplicate content]

Answer (score 0):

As aloisdg suggested you may use Silverlight Toolkit. Or you can use XNA for this purpose:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Flick;
   myTextBlock.ManipulationCompleted += myTextBlock_ManipulationCompleted;
}

private void myTextBlock_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
      GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
      switch (gesture.GestureType)
      {
        case GestureType.Flick:
            if (e.FinalVelocities.LinearVelocity.X < 0)
                        // do for one side
            if (e.FinalVelocities.LinearVelocity.X > 0)
                        // do for second side
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
  }
}
```