# How to use Image slider in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried image slider in windows phone.it does not work.

I want to slide images like jquery image slider one by one.Please help i have no idea.

Comment: _"it does not work"_ Is a terrible way to describe a problem. Does it not build? Does it crash (where)? Does the behavior differ from the one you expected (how)?

Comment: Hi Michael..Can you please see the link: http://web-b9f95b19-90dd-44dc-be45-1383111fac25.runnable.com I need to do like this image slider in windows phone 8

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can do that by using gesture service in Windows Phone for More about that go through this Link [how to get swipe in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/how-to-get-swipe-in-windows-phone-7)