# How to decide whether the user is performing a left or a right a swipe using CrossSlide(Gesture Recognizer) ? (WP8)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, gesture-recognition

How can I determine if the user is performing a left or a right `swipe`? I found a tutorial showing me how to use the CrossSlide Event. The code I got from the tutorial:

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox Name="TxtGestureNotes"
             Text="Hallo"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement element;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Page_Loaded();

    }


    public void GestureInputProcessor(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer gr, Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement target) {
        this.gestureRecognizer = gr;
        //Targeted UI element to be performing gestures on it.
        this.element = target;

        //Enable gesture settings for Tap, CrossSlide
        this.gestureRecognizer.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.Tap | GestureSettings.CrossSlide;

        // set up pointer event handlers. these receive input events that are used by the gesture recognizer
        this.element.PointerCanceled += OnPointerCanceled;
        this.element.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
        this.element.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
        this.element.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

        // set up event handlers to respond to gesture recognizer
        gestureRecognizer.Tapped += gestureRecognizer_Tapped;

        //CrossSliding distance thresholds are disabled by default. Use CrossSlideThresholds to set these values.
        Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds cst = new Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds();
        cst.SelectionStart = 2;
        cst.SpeedBumpStart = 3;
        cst.SpeedBumpEnd = 4;
        cst.RearrangeStart = 5;
        gestureRecognizer.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
        gestureRecognizer.CrossSlideThresholds = cst;
        gestureRecognizer.CrossSliding += gestureRecognizer_CrossSliding;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded() {
        // For makig gestures operations on Grid named as 'LayoutRoot'
        GestureInputProcessor(gestureRecognizer, LayoutRoot);
    }

    private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Remove event handlers of gesture recognizers events
        gestureRecognizer.Tapped -= gestureRecognizer_Tapped;
        gestureRecognizer.CrossSliding -= gestureRecognizer_CrossSliding;
    }

    // Pointer Events
    private void OnPointerCanceled(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.gestureRecognizer.CompleteGesture();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Route the events to the gesture recognizer
        this.gestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(this.element));
        //Set the pointer capture to the element being interacterd with
        this.element.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
        // Mark the event handled to prevent execution of default handlers
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.gestureRecognizer.ProcessUpEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(this.element));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.gestureRecognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(this.element));
    }

    private void gestureRecognizer_Tapped(GestureRecognizer sender, TappedEventArgs args) {
        TxtGestureNotes.Text = "Tap gesture recognized";
    }

    private void gestureRecognizer_CrossSliding(GestureRecognizer sender, CrossSlidingEventArgs args) {
        TxtGestureNotes.Text = "Slide gesture recognized";
    }


}
```

But how can i differentiate the swipe gesture such as right or left? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what did you get from the code you provided?

Comment: I get an app where I can swipe left and right and it is diplaying "Slide gesture recognized". But I want an app that can difference between a left and a right swipe. Like diplaying "Left slide recognized"/"Right slide recognized". @Kulasangar

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `GestureService` from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) in order to identify the `Swiping Gesture`.

[how to get swipe in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342326/)

Within the above sample try displaying something:

```
if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
  {
      // Display something
     MessageBox.Show("Swiped Right");
  }

  // User flicked towards right
  if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
  {
     // Display something
     MessageBox.Show("Swiped Right");
  }
```